# Change view after a post in AngualJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, ng-switch

I am doing a SPA. I am using ngResources and I have a really simple form.

User can compile it and after he submit the form should appear a new form with only a message that says something like this:
"Thank you to use our form ..."

I would like to avoid something like

```
$("#myForm").hide();
$("#myMessage").show();
```

because I think it is not the correct way to manage views in angular. I think I should use routing... Honestly I don't know...

In this moment I am using ngSwitch. I think ngSwitch is worst than using jQuery because ngSwitch change the scope of the view. So my model change from

```
<input data-ng-model="MyProp" ... />
```

to

```
<input data-ng-model="$parent.MyProp" ... />
```

I don't want to fill my form with `$parent`. I think it does not make sense in this context.
Which is the correct way to change view after in angularJs?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily managed that in your controller, You should declare `myProp` in some object.

```
$scope.options = {};
```

then place `myProp` inside options variable

```
<input data-ng-model="options.MyProp" ... />
```

Comment: mm... I think in this way I should access myProp in this way: `$parent.options.MyProp` because my scope is ngSwitch... no?

Comment: No..you wont need to do that..I will accessible as `options.MyProp`, give try for it, It follows angular prototypal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs looks at this